# Send out an email with delay

Tags: php, delay

I'm a beginner in php and I want to know if there is a way to send out an email with delay. I want to build a website where users can send an email to themselves with their goals and predictions, and after one year, they should receive their own email automatically.

Does anyone has an idea how I could do this?

Comment: when inserting on the db you could save the datetime it was inserted and datetime supposed to be sent. then use CRON to check, its up to you if you would like it to check daily,weekly,monthly

Answer (score 1):

You will have to take a look at CRON Jobs.  CRON Jobs can be set to run at certain intervals.  Hourly, Daily ect.

Here is a link to a [tutorial](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to store the email inside of a database or something.

Then you would need code that either auto starts 15 minutes after a new row has been added, or you would need code to check through the database for any unsent mail every few minutes. Usually "[cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)" is used for this.